# Confused about attr_accessor and attr_accessible in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

this is a simple signup application

schema.rb

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "email"
t.string   "password_hash"
t.string   "password_salt"
t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
```

User.rb

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
attr_accessor :password
before_save :encrypt_password
validates_confirmation_of :password
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
validates_presence_of :email
validates_uniqueness_of :email
.
.
.
```

**Why using password in both attr_accessible and attr_accessor?**

When i removed attr_accessor :password, in rails console, i got an error when executing:

```
user = User.new
user.password # => no method error
```

but when i execute this:

```
user = User.new
user.email # => nil
```

**which means user.email working without adding it in attr_accessor, why?!!**

and also this is working:

```
user = User.new
user.password_confirmation # => nil
```

but when i removed:

```
validates_confirmation_of :password
```

**it will not work, why??.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**attr_accessor** and **attr_accessible**, despite almost identical spelling, are absolutely different methods.

**attr_accessor**, a native Ruby method which defines a getter and a setter method for the instance of the class:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :password
end

u = User.new
u.password = "secret"
u.password # => "secret"
```

**attr_accessible** is a method brought by Rails and it is meant to "whitelist" *already existing* attributes of a model. Attributes enumerated in **attr_accessible** can be later changed via mass-assignment of model attributes (while other attributes will be blacklisted and not changeable):

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  # First, you define 2 attributes: "password" and "created_at"
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessor :created_at

  # Now you say that you want "password" attribute
  # to be changeable via mass-assignment, while making
  # "created_at" to be non-changeable via mass-assignment
  attr_accessible :password
end

a = Account.new

# Perform mass-assignment (which is usually done when you update
# your model using the attributes submitted via a web form)
a.update_attributes(:password => "secret", :created_at => Time.now)

a.password # => "secret"
# "password" is changed

a.created_at # => nil
# "created_at" remains not changed
```

You use **attr_accessible** to prevent meddling with some attributes of your models by "outsiders" (e.g. you wouldn't want your "Account.superadmin" attribute to be changeable via a simple form submission, which would be a bad security issue).

Note, that you can change the attributes individually, regardless of their "whitelisting/blacklisting" status:

```
a.created_at = Time.now

a.created_at # => 2012-09-16 10:03:14
```

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that this is meant to protect against the same [mass-assignment](http://blog.mhartl.com/2008/09/21/mass-assignment-in-rails-applications/) issues which allowed for the [GitHub hack](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/120981-github-hacked-millions-of-projects-at-risk-of-being-modified-or-deleted) earlier this year.

Comment: Great, but what did you mean by mass-assignment?

Comment: assignments in which one passes-in a whole array of attributes, rather than going "one at a time". For example, through use of: `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` in the example linked-to above. `attr_accessible` says "this is okay", while anything not-mentioned by `attr_accessible` it is assumed needs to be explicitly updated individually.

Comment: You mean that i can did this:   @user.name = 'bla bla'  even if it is not in attr_accessible ?

Comment: "Mass-assignment of attributes" would be a more precise wording for the term, if a shorter version sounds confusing ;-)
Method "update_attributes" is meant specifically for this purpose, because you can list several attributes there. However @user.password = "secret" is not "mass-assignment", it's a "single assignment" or "assignment of a single attribute".

Comment: Oh, and that is correct - you can update individual attributes, even if they are not listed in "attr_accessible". I've updated the original answer.

Comment: Great answers brothers, Thank you :)

Comment: Mass-assignment basically occurs here: `User.new(<here>)` and `user.update_attributes(<here>)` where a user for example submits a form which converts in to a Hash (`params` in your controller). A user can easily modify a form using for example Chrome's web inspector. She could add a checkbox field (`<input type="checkbox" name="admin" value="1"/>`) and submit that. If you have `attr_accessible :admin` in your User model, then you're basically allowing the user to change him or herself to an admin, as `admin` is now an **accessible** field, which is not what you want.