# Rails console outputs dirty/outdated data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

I'm following [Michael's Ruby on Rails tutorial (Chapter 6.2.2)](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec-presence_validation) and when I go to the `rails console --sandbox` to attempt to create Users the outputs come totally outdated.

I update a user's attribute, I return the user and the console outputs `nil` for all attributes. However if I output the `user.attribute` the data is there.

The first save fails because a user must have a name, though I had this problem even before addind validations.

What am I missing here? I followed all the instructions and I'm doing pretty basic stuff. I'm executing the following commands:

```
$ rails console --sandbox
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 4.0.2)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit

2.1.0 :001 > user = User.new(name: "", email: "mhartl@example.com")
 => #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, citizen_number: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.1.0 :002 > user.save
   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => false 
2.1.0 :003 > user.valid?
 => false 
2.1.0 :004 > user.name = "Bob"
 => "Bob" 
2.1.0 :005 > user.valid?
 => true 
2.1.0 :006 > user
 => #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, citizen_number: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.1.0 :007 > user.save
   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (6.2ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 08 Feb 2014 19:15:37 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sat, 08 Feb 2014 19:15:37 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => true 
2.1.0 :008 > user
 => #<User id: 1, name: nil, email: nil, citizen_number: nil, created_at: "2014-02-08 19:15:37", updated_at: "2014-02-08 19:15:37">
```

---

My user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :citizen_number

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  VALID_CITIZEN_NUMBER_REGEX = /[1-9]\d{7,}/
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :citizen_number, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_CITIZEN_NUMBER_REGEX }, uniqueness: true

  before_save { lowercase_email() }

  def lowercase_email() 
    self.email = email.downcase
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DiAlex, do you have the code that produced this? I'd like to try it. Since the issue is actually something that happens before the save but after "initialization", I can't see how reload or the validations matter.

**Update**: Based on the tests and back and forth with you, I think your problem is related with the misuse of `attr_accessor` and `attr_accessible`.

Try removing `:citizen_number` from the `attr_accessor`. I tried that and your code started working (passing all your tests) and the console started outputting the correct values too.

Comment: I continued the tutorial and ignored this problem, so the most up-to-date source has more validations. Nevertheless you should have a pretty stable version here: https://github.com/dialex/dcid/tree/288ac1608c97117ab766e6d2c4c051b084ea8804 I'm also a n00b so yeah :P

Comment: DiAlex - I cloned the modeling-users branch (the others don't have a user model).  Indeed, I rec'd the same errors and weirdness, with or without the validations. AND when I save, it it saves, but the data is still weird.  See the results here (https://gist.github.com/jmcbri/9021295)

Comment: I also created a fresh apps, and created a user model, and it does what you'd expect: (https://gist.github.com/jmcbri/9021337)    Now we have to figure out what is different between your app and the default. Doubt I'll be able to do that, but I'll try.

Comment: OK, if I removed the  attr_accessor in your User model, in your repo, it works.  Going to look at it more, but it's probably related to the whole whitelisting, thing, and also, I think you (and I) missed that you probably wanted attr_accessible, not attr_accessor (though maybe not for the password, and I think you may not want any of this, as the security on this stuff is moving into the controller). See (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444706/confused-about-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible-in-rails), and (http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-4-quick-look-strong-parameters/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`reload`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reload)

`user.reload` should give your up to date user with the correct attributes, as explained in the [Documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reload), it reloads the attributes of this object from the database, so you can now get the object attributes as expected, if they saved correctly

Comment: That gives an error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User without an ID`, since the User is not saved. The console should (I guess) output the correct data even before saving the user.

Comment: then you might not be saving the user

Answer (score 0):

Diogo, something is preventing your `user.save`. After the first attempt of `user.save`, try `user.errors`. This will give you a hash with the errors that prevented your model to save.

Most probably you will find an error in your DB Scheme, as the `user.valid?` returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without sandbox mode? Perhaps it is somehow restricting the write.

```
rails console
```